# How to use date command inside Popen?

Tags: python-3.x, date

I cannot use parameters when invoking date command inside Popen.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, Python 3.6.7. I am trying to just print date by invokin `date` command from shell, unfortunately I got errors which says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./123.py", line 15, in <module>
    print_date()
  File "./123.py", line 9, in print_date
    MyOut = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "date '+%S'": "date '+%S'"
```

Code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import time
import os

cmd = "date '+%S'"
def print_date():
    MyOut = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout,stderr = MyOut.communicate()
    print(stdout)
    print(stderr)

os.system(cmd)
print_date()
```

Could anyone explain what went wrong, and why Python tries to find file `"date '+%S'"` ? 
It works when we change cmd to `cmd = "date"`, so what is correct way of passing `'+%S'` ?

Comment: Have you tried using `subprocess.run()` that works excellent for me I never touch `.Popen()`

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to pass a command to `Popen()` is with a list.  Try this:

```
cmd = ["date" '+%S']
```